# How to check a mac process exists by process name

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, macos, cocoa

I need to kill a mac process but before that do I need to check, if it actually exists or not?

I have tried to use C++ method `system("killall  process_name");` to kill process by name.

But I think I should also check the process is actually running or not. Could anyone please let me know, how it can be done?

Comment: What if it ends after you check but before you kill it? "Do, or do not; there is no check."

Comment: You should actually use signals for that, instead of `system`. And besides it does not matter if it exists or not, if it does it will recieve a signal from `killall` if it does not then nothing will happen.

Comment: @Alan Stokes What if the process was in "not running" state for a long time say and continued to remain in the "not running" state..Because system() doesn't through any exception, so i cannot use try-catch block. Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @iharob could you give me example, how signals can be used here?

Comment: Actually i am trying to kill a process from my application, and i just need a suggestion should i put a check- if (process_running->kill it) else ->do_nothing?

Comment: I don't get it either.  Just try to kill it and soak up any error/exception.

Comment: So, you are saying i should not care about any error/exception, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely use killall - the one you are already using. It is harmless, even if the process is not existing.

Since you have tagged Objective-C, I assume you are fine with cocoa solutions. This is one another easy way to kill a process if you have the process name in hand. It uses apple script. Here you need not check whether it is running or not.

```
NSString *processName = @"Microsoft Outlook";
NSString *scriptSource = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tell application \"%@\" to quit",processName];
NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:scriptSource];
[script executeAndReturnError:nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
BOOL processIsRunning = system("ps -Ac | grep 'AProcessName' > /dev/null") == 0;
```

Or, if you want to check for a string in particular:

```
BOOL processIsRunning = system("ps -ef | grep 'AUniqueString' | grep -iv grep > /dev/null") == 0;
```